# Using VBA to place multiple barcodes in one cell, while retaining delete and undo functions.

Tags: excel, vba

In trying to come across for a solution to get getting multiple barcodes into one cell, I discovered a solution for it made a few years back.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C10")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim vNew As Variant
        vNew = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Target = Target.Value & Chr(10) & vNew
        Else
            Target = vNew
        End If
        'Target.Offset(1,0).Activate
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Courtesy of User [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped)

The issue that I'm facing now is like stated in that comment thread three years ago.  This kills undo and any editing of the cell, as well throwing up an error when trying to use the search feature to find the cell.

I'm unfamiliar with VBA, but if anyone could provide some help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: An alternative could be to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to capture the "prior" value when the cell is selected, instead of using Undo to revert the cell.

Comment: For future reference, changes made from macros can't be undone (as in ctrl + z). A workaround will have to be used (as @TimWilliams suggests)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. With that being the case, what would keep this from allowing edits to be made to the cell.  After the codes are scanned in, in the case of a duplicate getting scanned in, it can not be deleted or edited. If you try to do so, the cell will just duplicate it and you'll end up with three duplicates instead of one. As well as the cell itself being unable to be cleared.